# spring integration flow loses response

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

i have 2 flows

One is an http inbound gateway

```
        return IntegrationFlow.from((Http.inboundGateway(getEndpointUrl())
        .requestMapping(r -> r.methods(HttpMethod.valueOf(getHttpMethodType()))
        .headerMapper(httpHeaderMapper())
        .requestPayloadType(String.class)
        .replyTimeout(getHttpReplyTimeout())
        .errorChannel(adapterErrorChannel())))
        .handle(validationService, "validationService")

        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction("some-id", m -> UUID.randomUUID().toString()))

        .publishSubscribeChannel(c -> c

            .subscribe(s -> s

                .routeToRecipients(r -> r

                    .recipient("backupAChannel", m -> doBackupA())

                    .recipient("backupBChannel", m -> doBackupB())

                    .defaultOutputToParentFlow())

                .channel("nullChannel"))

            .subscribe(s -> s

                .handle(messagePayloadService, "mapMessagePayload")


                .enrich(e -> e.requestChannel("claimCheck.input").headerExpression("claimCheck", "payload"))

                .handle("integrationGateway", "process")))
        .get();
```

After the HTTP input is received successfully, I create a response and send it out with the following

```
        MessageChannel replyChannel = (MessageChannel) headers.get("replyChannel");

        ...

        return replyChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(json).setHeader(HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE,
              "Im a teapot").setHeader("Content-Type", HEADER_FMT).build());
```

The json has the format {"a": "b"}

The response IS being built but it is not being sent back to whoever sent data to the http inbound gateway

Instead of status "Im a teapot" they get 200 and no json

In the response builder code above, replyChannel has the value GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@12345

What's odd to me is errorChannel shows the same value.

Is that how default channels are supposed to work?

The other flow is

```
        return f -> f

        .<MessageItemPayloadInterface>handle((p, h) -> {

            Object o = getOutput(p, h);
            if (o == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return o;

        }, e -> e.id("channelA"))

        .<MessageItemPayloadInterface>handle((p, h) -> {
            saveData(p, h);
            return p;
        }, e -> e.id("channelB").transactional(true))

        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction(IntegrationHeaders.PRODUCER_EVENT_KEY,
            m -> {
                String header = generateHeader(m.getPayload(), m.getHeaders());
                return header == null ? "" : header;
            }))

        .<MessageItemPayloadInterface>handle((p, h) -> {

            Object o = tellTheWorld(p, h);
            if (o == null {
                return null;
            }
            return o;
        }, e -> e.id("channelC"))

        .publishSubscribeChannel(a -> a

            .subscribe(b -> b

                .routeToRecipients(r -> r

                    .recipient("channelD", true)

                    .defaultOutputToParentFlow())

                .channel("nullChannel"))

            .subscribe(d -> d

                .handle((p, h) -> {

                    housekeeping();

                    return p;
                })

                .channel("nullChannel")))

        .channel("nullChannel");
```

and its reply channel and error channel are the same as the http inbound gateway's

Which really is confusing.  Are they supposed to be shared across diff flows?

The problem is, it looks like the output of the 2nd flow is being returned to whoever called the http inbound gateway.

The original code was written in spring integration 5.5.11 and the misbehaving code has been upgraded to spring integration 6.1.5

Why isn't the expected output of the http inbound gateway flow being sent to the caller?

Why is the expected output of the 2nd flow being sent instead?

Is this some kind of fundamental change between versions?

EDIT:  01/16 I have reformatted this post, answered some questions and provided additional details at [spring integration flow loses response - with added information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77830027/spring-integration-flow-loses-response-with-added-information)

Comment: I'm sorry, but in your question there is no connection between code snippets you show us. It is not clear where you use that `replyChannel.send()`. How that second flow is involved? The `TemporaryReplyChannel` is indeed the same instance for both `replyChannel` and `errorChannel` headers. That's how request-reply pattern (or to be precise: Return Address) is implemented. Would be great if you are able to share with us a simple project to let us to reproduce on our side. It is not clear, though, why would use `defaultOutputToParentFlow()` just to end with a `nullChannel` afterwards...

Comment: Artem - thank you for the reply.  I have inherited this code.  I have no idea why any decisions were made but I'll tell you what I've observed.  The second flow is executed after the first.  The first receives data via a POST to a rest endpoint and the 2nd operates upon it.  This is working as expected until I upgraded versions of spring integration.  Now the last message emitted by the 2nd flow is being returned as the output from the first.  I am unsure if the original author intended to shut this off via the nullChannel or what needs to be communicated via defaultOutputToParentFlow().

Comment: The replyChannel.send is being used by code executed by the first flow.

Comment: Yeah... Without the whole picture and some logs it is hard to say what is going on. Doesn't look, though, that your second flow returns ever: it ends up with a `nullChannel` in all its branches. I suggest to enable `debug` for `org.springframework.integration` and even Message History to observe how your message travels after receiving that HTTP request. I may guess that `handle("integrationGateway", "process")` is the place where you'd like to produce a reply. Then you just need to `return`. The framework will take care about reply producing for you.

Comment: i have dumped the logs as you requested.  Can you suggest what I should look for?

Comment: Find the message with request and try to follow its path in the integration flow. See also all the migration guides since there, maybe that can give you a clue what should be changed: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-5.x-to-6.0-Migration-Guide, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-6.0-to-6.1-Migration-Guide. Since you don't show the whole code, it is hard to judge what is going on.

Comment: i'll do the above and post the results here.  i'm curious what additional code you'd need to see?  i've posted the flow definitions and all that's left is the code that operates on the output of the first flow and the code that communicates back and forth with the 2nd.  what in particular do you  need to see?  i'll strip down what i have and add it.

Comment: Yeah... I'd like to see the whole from the HTTP request to its reply. And in the description of the question you point to the code which should return reply, but it does not and instead that one does that for you. I still don't see how that second flow is connected and if it is relevant at all. You may try to strip the current code yourself making it working at least somehow. And then bring back some required pieces. For example, I don't think that `routeToRecipients()` makes some difference for the reply you'd expect. Therefore remove its whole `subscribe()` part.

Comment: I have started a new thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77830027/spring-integration-flow-loses-response-with-added-information thinking it might be cleaner to read