# spring integration flow loses response - with added information

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

This is a follow up to [spring integration flow loses response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77809736/spring-integration-flow-loses-response) which hopefully provides more info as described by Artem Bilan

This is the first flow

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnExpression(" condition evaluates to TRUE ")
public class BeanDefA {

  @Bean
  IntegrationFlow rest() {
    return IntegrationFlow.from((Http.inboundGateway("/myEndpoint")
        .requestMapping(r -> r.methods(HttpMethod.valueOf("POST")))
        .headerMapper(restConfig.httpHeaderMapper())
        .requestPayloadType(String.class)
        .replyTimeout(5000)
        .errorChannel(exceptionConfig.adapterErrorChannel())))

        .handle(hmacValidationService, "validateHMACAuthHeaders")

        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction("message-correlation-id", m -> UUID.randomUUID().toString()))

        .publishSubscribeChannel(c -> c

            .subscribe(s -> s

                .routeToRecipients(r -> r

                    .recipient("backupChannelA", m -> true)

                    .recipient("backupChannelB", m -> false)

                    .defaultOutputToParentFlow())

                .channel("nullChannel"))

            .subscribe(s -> s

                .handle(messagePayloadService, "mapMessagePayload")

                .enrich(e -> e.requestChannel("claimCheck.input").headerExpression("claimCheck", "payload"))

                .handle("integrationGateway", "process")))
        .get();
  }
```

}

This line

```
.handle(messagePayloadService, "mapMessagePayload")
```

attaches a bean reference that defines the below method

```
    public boolean sendReply(Map<String, Object> headers) {
    MessageChannel replyChannel = (MessageChannel) headers.get("replyChannel");

    Message m = MessageBuilder.withPayload('"Status":"Success","ErrorMessage":""'')
       .setHeader(HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE,response.getStatusCode())
       .setHeader("Content-Type", HEADER_FMT).build();

    return replyChannel.send(m);

}
```

This is the output I wish to return to whoever sent the POST to /myEndpoint

Here's the 2nd flow

```
    @Configuration
@ConditionalOnExpression(" condition evaluates to TRUE ")
public class BeanDefB

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow dbWrite() {
    return f -> f

        <MessageItemPayloadInterface>handle((p, h) -> {

            Object o = writer.filterAndEnrich(p, h);

            if (o == null && h.get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT) != null) {
                return null;
            }

            return o;

        }, e -> e.id("dbWriterFilterAndEnrichEndpoint"))

        .<MessageItemPayloadInterface>handle((p, h) -> {

            writer.save(p, h);
            return p;

        }, e -> e.id("dbWriterSaveEndpoint").transactional(false))

        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction(IntegrationHeaders.PRODUCER_EVENT_KEY,
            m -> {
                String header = writer.generateEventHeader(m.getPayload(), m.getHeaders());
                return header == null ? "" : header;
            }))

        .<MessageItemPayloadInterface>handle((p, h) -> {

            Object o = writer.notify(p, h);

            if (o == null && h.get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT) != null) {
                LOG("this is an error");
                h.get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class).acknowledge();
                return null;
            }

            return o;

        }, e -> e.id("dbWriterNotifyEndpoint"))

        .publishSubscribeChannel(a -> a

            .subscribe(b -> b

                .routeToRecipients(r -> r

                    .recipient("eventProducerChannel", true)

                    .defaultOutputToParentFlow())

                .channel("nullChannel"))

            .subscribe(d -> d

                .handle((p, h) -> {

                    if (h.get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT) != null) {

                        LOG.debug("Message processed! Headers= " + h + ". Payload= " + p);
                        h.get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class).acknowledge();

                    }
                    return p;
                })

                .channel("nullChannel")))

        .channel("nullChannel");
  }

}
```

In the above "writer" is a bean that contains business logic.

Its methods are invoked, performing actions based on Message contents and returning NULL if there was some kind of error.

The output of writer.notify(p, h) is a message I wish to send via Kafka and, for some reason, its now being returned to the poor soul who POSTed to /myEndpoint

I have turned on debugging as we discussed previously and the only time I see '"Status":"Success","ErrorMessage":""'' is when I log it prior to returning it

I do not see it mentioned in any of the messages produced by the processing done by either flow.

This is, I think, an "orchestrator" class that puts it all together.

Its run time actions are controlled by config variables accessible at run time.

```
@Configuration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class IntegrationProvider {

  public final Config config;

  public IntegrationProvider(Config config) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow main() {
    return f -> f.routeToRecipients(r -> r.recipient(config.getEndpointType() + ".input"));
  }

  @MessagingGateway(name = "integrationGateway", errorChannel = "errorChannel")
  public interface IntegrationGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "main.input")
    void start(Object msg);

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "process.input")
    void process(Message<MessagePayloadInterface> msg);

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "write.input")
    void write(Message<MessageItemPayloadInterface> msg);

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "dbWrite.input")
    void dbWrite(Message<MessageItemPayloadInterface> msg);

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "send.input")
    void send(Message<MessageItemPayloadInterface> msg);
  }
```

}

Is it possible something changed between versions 5 & 6 and now flow 2 is somehow sharing the replyChannel with flow 1?

Or is relying on replyChannel as a way to communicate '"Status":"Success","ErrorMessage":""'' as the POST response the incorrect thing to do?

Comment: That is still not helpful and confusing.  You do `replyChannel.send(m)`, but that `.handle(messagePayloadService, "mapMessagePayload")` is not the end of the flow. And there is no info yet how that second flow is called.

Comment: I think I have the answers.  All the flows are defined as beans (I've modified the posted code to show this) that are available to an orchestrator class I've posted above.  The end of a defined flow IS the end of that flow BUT flows can be linked together.

Comment: So, does it work now? All your `@Gateway` contracts are `void`, therefore no any reply is expected from any of them. We don't see how your `main` flow is called, but that `dbWrite` is also not called from the mentioned `rest`. Therefore it is not related to the question.

Comment: No.  Its not working.  Let me try asking my question a different way.  What is the proper way for the flow defined by rest() bean above to return the json {"Status":"Success","ErrorMessage":""} and http status 202?  That's the problem I'm facing.

Comment: The last handler in the flow must just return that text. The framework then propagate this reply properly to the HTTP response. Right now I'm not sure in your logic at all. You try to send into a `replyChannel` manually and then you try to continue the flow to somewhere which is `void`.

Comment: The original author of the code is no longer available to explain his logic so I'm as confused as you are.  It sounds like you're saying returning an http response via a replyChannel manually is not the correct use of Spring Integration.  Is that correct?

Comment: Unusual, but yes: supposed to work. Consider also copy all those `headers` into the message you send to the `replyChannel`. It might lose something required for the proper correlation. Hard to judge from your complex code though. Even if I can come up with some simple sample for such a use-case, it doesn't mean that something might be missed because the whole picture of your complex solution is lost.

Comment: I finally found the last handler (all the flows are defined as beans; the ones you want are enabled by a configuration file).  The last flow logged the kafka message being sent.  I added .channel("nullChannel") to the end of the logging flow and it started to work as well expected.  How did it work before?  Beats the hell out of me.  Thank you for all your help.  You gave me something to look for.

Comment: You said "logged". Looks like you are missing this migration recipe: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-5.x-to-6.0-Migration-Guide#log-at-the-end-of-a-flow

Comment: yeah, it seemed odd to me there was a whole separate logging flow when the .log(String) method was used all over the place in the code

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem of the target application that `log()` operator is used in the end of `IntegrationFlow` making it, essentially, as a request-reply. According to the Migration Guide from `5.5` to `6.0`, the `nullChannel()` is recommended to be used in the end of flow, if there is no need in returning a reply upstream: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-5.x-to-6.0-Migration-Guide#log-at-the-end-of-a-flow